# how to inject Environment on application context

Tags: java, spring

I'm currently working with legacy code and I wanna read some properties from the Environment. I know this would be easily done using spring boot with:

```
@Autowired
Environment environment;
```

But, since I'm wiring all the components using an application-context.xml file, I don't know how to wire the Environment there,

```
<bean name="myBean" class="com.acme.MyClass">
???
</bean>
```

Comment: `<context:annotation-config/>` is your friend. Have you added that to your context xml?

Comment: Not yet, where should I write that?

Comment: Anywhere in the beans section of your context xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your help @volveira89 @rmlan

Using the xml file, this is working:

```
<bean name="myBean" class="com.acme.MyClass">
   <constructor-arg ref="environment"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have no experience in Spring XML config. You should look at this example by Spring team: https://spring.io/blog/2011/01/04/green-beans-getting-started-with-spring-mvc/

You need something like this in your application-context.xml:

```
<!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components 
to configure as beans -->
<!-- @Controller, @Service, @Configuration, etc. -->
<context:component-scan base-package="xyz.sample.baremvc" />

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Now your,

```
@Autowired 
Environment environment
```

should work!

Comment: just wondering, is not a way to just add it in the xml application-context file instead of add support for annotations?

Comment: Seems like you find the solution :)